# How to change the pjsip register account at the time of re-registration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sip, voip, pjsip

I am working on with pjsip for iOS, I have configured the pjsip and able to register and reregister for specific time interval, but there is a scenario where I want to change the pjsip account details at the time of re register with new details but I havent found anything on google which can guide how to change it.

If someone have a idea about this please guide me through how to change the `pjsua_acc_config` details at time of re registration, I get the method call at the time of re registration.

```
static void on_reg_state2(pjsua_acc_id acc_id, pjsua_reg_info *info) {
    PJ_LOG(3,(__FILE__, "%s: Account %d Reason %.*s Status %d code %d CurrentOp %d",
              __FUNCTION__, acc_id, info->cbparam->reason.slen, info->cbparam->reason.ptr,
              info->cbparam->status,info->cbparam->code, info->cbparam->regc));
}
```

Comment: what account details, are you trying to change?

Comment: Like first time I have registered user with sip using pjsua_acc_config details and now user connected, then if any case server goes down so i want that config could change.

Answer (score 2):

get account configuration for account id, and set the fields to whatever required in on_reg_state2 function.

```
if (pjsua_acc_is_valid(acc_id))
 {
    pjsua_acc_set_default(acc_id);
    pjsua_acc_config acc_cfg;
    pj_status_t status;
    pjsua_acc_config_default(&acc_cfg);

    acc_cfg.id = pj_str(id);
    acc_cfg.reg_uri = pj_str(registrar);
    acc_cfg.cred_count = 1;
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].scheme = pj_str("Digest");
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str(realm);
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_str(uname);
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = 0;
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].data = pj_str(passwd);

    acc_cfg.publish_enabled = PJ_TRUE;

  }
```

Comment: I have added the acc_cfg.id = pj_str(sipId); acc_cfg.reg_uri = pj_str(regUri); into this block because I want to change them only but they are not working, I am getting the same registrar all the time, not updated one.

Comment: This code is not doing much except modifying some local (stack based) variable. Calling pjsua_acc_modify would actually do something, although I'm not sure if modifying account inside account callback is actually good idea - it might work and be safe now (i.e. with specific pjsip version) but I would rather set some flag here and then do actual modification from application thread.

Comment: @TMSZ I have used pjsua_acc_modify but still no luck with that, what could be the alternative to handle this scenario?

Comment: Have you checked pjsua_acc_modify for error code? Also account id and registrar are so essential that I'm not sure if deleting account and adding another one would not be cleaner.

Comment: @TMSZ When I change the acc_modify code runs fine but the log says its still connecting to previous IP and when I shut that IP server then get request timeout. If you have any idea over it, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

> Its like same as re register. 
>      remove current account and add new one

```
if (_sip_acc_id != PJSUA_INVALID_ID){

    //        pjsua_acc_info info;
    //        pjsua_acc_get_info(_sip_acc_id, &info);
    //
    //        if (info.has_registration){
    pj_status_t statusDelete = pjsua_acc_del(_sip_acc_id);
    if (statusDelete != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        pjsua_perror(THIS_FILE, "Error removing new account", status);
        [app displayParameterError: @"Error removing new account."];
    }
    //        }
}

status = pjsua_acc_add(&acc_cfg, PJ_TRUE, &_sip_acc_id);
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
{
    pjsua_perror(THIS_FILE, "Error adding new account", status);
    [app displayParameterError: @"Error adding new account."];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is guide for recomendationabout PJSIP You can click this [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsua__acc__config.htm)